# Drawing subpixels in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, graphics, javafx-2, javafx-8

For a JavaFX graphics program that I'm trying to create I would like to be able to divide each pixel into 4 subpixels and draw them. Is this possible in JavaFX (or in any other Java graphics library)?

Comment: Aren't pixels, by definition, atomic?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, thanks for taking the time to post. I've read that it's possible to do subpixel manipulation in OpenGL and Python but I'm not sure about JavaFX.

Comment: You want to scale the image by a factor 2?

Comment: @Carigenicate [pixels are not necessarily atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX will render sub pixels for text when [`FontSmoothingType.LCD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/FontSmoothingType.html#LCD) is used.

As far as I know, there are no mechanism in JavaFX where you can specify using [sub pixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) for any other graphics primitives than text (e.g. lines and circles).

Even though you can't specify the rendering type for other primitives, they may or may not be rendered using sub pixel rendering (I don't know, though I would guess that sub pixel rendering would not be used even when the primitives are rendered using [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing)).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try to find another way of doing what I want to do without manipulating subpixels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  By default if you draw to an integer pixel on a canvas, it will draw a dot "between" actual screen pixels, i.e. it will anti-alias with the neighboring pixels.  If you offset by 0.5, then it will draw exactly on the pixel.  So you can draw sub-pixels by using values between 0.5 and 1.5.  For example if you draw a horizontal line with Y1=100.5 and Y2=101.5, you will see anti-aliasing in between.  You can also set line widths non-integer, in which case it will dim or anti-alias the pixel an appropriate amount.  I'm not sure about FontSmoothing, but this is part of the canvas GraphicsContext.

Comment: Meh, ok rereading what subpixel rendering really means, I've not come across that for JavaFX when drawing lines.  I've only come across presumably regular anti-aliasing.